# Model records ordering in Spine.js

Tags: model-view-controller, javascript-framework, spine.js

As I can see in the Spine.js sources the Model.each() function returns Model's records in the order of their IDs. This is completely unreliable in scenarios where ordering is important: long person list etc.

Can you suggest a way to keep original records ordering (in the same order as they've arrived via refresh() or similar functions) ?

P.S.
Things are even worse because by default Spine.js internally uses new GUIDs as IDs. So records order is completely random which unacceptable.

EDIT:
Seems that in last commit https://github.com/maccman/spine/commit/116b722dd8ea9912b9906db6b70da7948c16948a

they made it possible, but I have not tested it myself because I switched from Spine to Knockout.

Comment: for now I figured it out by using JavaScript's Array.sort()

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/spinejs/browse_thread/thread/857e463e93f5bf2c

Answer (score 2):

Bumped into the same problem learning spine.js. I'm using pure JS, so i was neglecting the the contact example http://spinejs.com/docs/example_contacts which helped out on this one. As a matter of fact, you can't really keep the ordering from the server this way, but you can do your own ordering with javascript.

Notice that i'm using the *Element Pattern* here. (http://spinejs.com/docs/controller_patterns)

First you set the function which is gonna do the sorting inside the model:

```
/*Extending the Student Model*/
Student.extend({

    nameSort: function(a,b) {
        if ((a.name || a.email) > (b.name || b.email)) 
            return 1; 
        else 
            return -1
    }
});
```

Then, in the students controller you set the elements using the sort:

```
/*Controller that manages the students*/
var Students = Spine.Controller.sub({

           /*code ommited for simplicity*/

            addOne: function(student){
            var item = new StudentItem({item: student});
            this.append(item.render());
    },

    addAll: function(){
            var sortedByName = Student.all().sort(Student.nameSort);
            var _self = this;
            $.each(sortedByName, function(){_self.addOne(this)});
    },


});
```

And that's it.